# make it constantly blinks / glows when mouse hovers over the image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created an image animation using CSS and Javascript, and I would like to make it constantly blinks / glows (with the pink colour) when the mouse cursor hovers on the image. how should I change the code and using the javascript to achieve this?

Here is the source code that I've tried.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  outline: 0;
  border: none;
}
body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: #22232e;
}
button {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: transparent;
  position: relative;
}
button .btn-img{
  padding: 10px 15px;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #e0ffff;
  border: 2px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
  border-radius: 15px;
  background: rgba(0,73,88,0.05);
  backdrop-filter: blur(15px);
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: 0.2s;
}
button::before{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  bottom: -3px;
  width: 25%;
  height: 10px;
  background: #00c2cb;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transition: .5s;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,194,203,0.5);
}
button:hover::before{
  bottom: 0;
  height: 40%;
  width: 90%;
  border-radius: 30px;
  transition-delay: 0.5s;
  /* background: #ffbd1f; */
  background: #db0079;
}
```

```html
<button>
  <span class="btn-img">
    <img src="https://img1.daumcdn.net/thumb/R48x0/?scode=mtistory2&fname=https%3A%2F%2Fblog.kakaocdn.net%2Fdn%2FtKZbq%2FbtsEb7zLet0%2FHDOJKKBGmhp3kWrFZXXTFk%2Fimg.png"></br><div id="tr" style="display: table-cell; text-align: center; color: rgb(255,255,255)";>Sample
  </span>
</button>
```

to see the demo, please take a look at the [codepen](https://codepen.io/cpadhwfr-the-decoder/pen/rNREBym).

thank you.

Comment: You might want to reconsider this.  [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blink_element), [html.com](https://html.com/tags/blink/), [UX](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/108139/why-is-display-of-conditional-blinking-data-rarely-implemented-in-modern-applica), [historyoftheweb](https://thehistoryoftheweb.com/blink-marquis-tag/)

Comment: As @Tibrogargan just said you might reconsider that idea. For many reasons, it is not considered a good UI practice. But if you really insist, then there is no need for any javascript. With modern css you can just use a simple css animation.

Comment: maybe a subtle "breathing" effect would be better

Comment: @JaromandaX Thanks for your suggestion. but as I am a Javascript newbie, need some help to implement ideas into reality. Though, would like to practice  a lot.

Comment: no javascript required - just like in the answer you accepted, though, I'd recommend more subtle :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Animation for a more subtle "breathing" effect on the pink colour - using [css animation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation)

The breathing effect is achieved by animating the opacity of the ::before pseudo element from 1 to 0.5 and back to 1

```
animation: 1500ms ease-in-out 1s infinite alternate breathing;
```

To explain the values in animation - the above is short for

```
animation-duration: 1500ms; /* could also use 1.5s here */
animation-timing-function: ease-in-out; /* I find this pleasing for the effect */
animation-delay: 1s; /* so the breathing starts right when the transition ends */
animation-iteration-count: infinite; /* self explanatory */
animation-direction: alternate; /* i.e. alternating */
animation-name: breathing; /* i.e. the @keyframes to use */
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  outline: 0;
  border: none;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: #22232e;
}

button {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: transparent;
  position: relative;
}

button .btn-img {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #e0ffff;
  border: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  border-radius: 15px;
  background: rgba(0, 73, 88, 0.05);
  backdrop-filter: blur(15px);
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

button::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  bottom: -3px;
  width: 25%;
  height: 10px;
  background: #00c2cb;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transition: .5s;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 194, 203, 0.5);
}

button:hover::before {
  bottom: 0;
  height: 40%;
  width: 90%;
  border-radius: 30px;
  transition-delay: 0.5s;
  /* background: #ffbd1f; */
  background: #db0079;
  /* added animation */
  animation: 1500ms ease-in-out 1s infinite alternate breathing;
}
/* key frames for animation */
@keyframes breathing {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
}
```

```html
<button>
  <span class="btn-img">
    <img src="https://img1.daumcdn.net/thumb/R48x0/?scode=mtistory2&fname=https%3A%2F%2Fblog.kakaocdn.net%2Fdn%2FtKZbq%2FbtsEb7zLet0%2FHDOJKKBGmhp3kWrFZXXTFk%2Fimg.png"></br><div id="tr" style="display: table-cell; text-align: center; color: rgb(255,255,255)";>Sample
  </span>
</button>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot to your effort and comments next to your code, it's keep me motivated to learn something new! very helpful! :)